# Making divs center if side by side or stacked

Tags: css, layout

I have two divs that are side by side if the window/resolution allows, and stacked one on top of the other if it doesn't.

I need them to be center in both cases. I have managed to get them center for one case or the other but not both.

Layout:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="center">
      <div class="left">LEFT</div>
      <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.left {
    background:blue;
    height:200px;
    width:250px;
}
div.right {
    background:green;
    height:300px;
    width:250px;
}
div.center {
    text-align: left;

}
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.container div {
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zygnz/1784/

This way has them centered so long as the window is bigger than the side by side elements, but it aligns left when they are one on top of the other.

How can I make it centered for both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `.center` class to `text-align: center`:

```
div.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks :)